# Maximum number of threads and multithreading

Tags: multithreading, cpu, processor, cpu-cores

I'm tripping up on the multithreading concept.

For example, my processor has 2 cores (and with hyper threading) 2 threads per core totaling to 4 thread. So does this mean my CPU can execute four separate instructions simultaneously? Is each thread capable of being a multi-thread?

Comment: A single core can already execute [multiple instructions concurrently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscalar_processor).  Four cores can execute four distinct threads at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

> So does this mean my CPU can execute four separate instructions simultaneously? Is each thread capable of being a multi-thread?

In short to both, yes.

A CPU can only execute 1 single instruction per phase in a clock cycle, due to certain factors like pipelining, a CPU might be able to pass multiple instructions through the different phases in a single clock cycle, and the frequency of the clock might be extremely fast, but it's still only 1 instruction at a time.

As an example, `NOP` is an x86 assembly instruction which the CPU interprets as "no operation this cycle" that's 1 instruction out of the hundreds or thousands (and more) that are executed from something even as simple as:

```
int main(void)
{
    while (1) { /* eat CPU */ }
    return 0;
}
```

A *CPU thread of execution* is one in which a series of instructions (a thread of instructions) are being executed, it does not matter from what "application" the instructions are coming from, a CPU does not know about high level concepts (like applications), that's a function of the OS.

So if you have a computer with 2 (or 4/8/128/etc.) CPU's that share the same memory (cache/RAM), then you can have 2 (or more) CPU's that can run 2 (or more) instructions at (literally) the exact same time. Keep in mind that these are machine instructions that are running at the same time (i.e. the physical side of the software).

An *OS level thread* is something a bit different. While the CPU handles the physical side of the execution, the OS handles the logical side. The above code breaks down into more than 1 instruction and when executed, actually gets run on more than 1 CPU (in a multi-CPU aware environment), even though it's a single "thread" (at the OS level), the OS schedules when to run the next instructions and on what CPU (based on the OS's thread scheduling policy, which is different amongst the various OS's). So the above code will eat up 100% CPU usage per a given "time slice" on that CPU it's running on.

This "slicing" of "time" (also known as [preemptive computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29)) is why an OS can run multiple applications "at the same time", it's not *literally*<sup>1</sup> at the same time since a CPU can only handle 1 instruction at a time, but to a human (who can barely comprehend the length of 1 second), it appears "at the same time".

<sup>1) except in the case with a multi-CPU setup, then it might be literally the same time.</sup>

When an application is run, the kernel (the OS) actually spawns a separate thread (a kernel thread) to run the application on, additionally the application can request to create another external thread (i.e. spawning another process or forking), or by creating an internal thread by calling the OS's (or programming languages) API which actually call lower level kernel routines that spawn and maintain the context switching of the spawned thread, additionally, any created thread is also capable of calling the same API's to spawn other separate threads (thus a thread is capable of being "multi-threaded").

Multi-threading (in the sense of applications and operating systems), is not necessarily portable, so while you might learn Java or C# and use their API's (i.e. [`Thread.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9fyxz7d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html)), utilizing the actual OS API's as provided (i.e. [`CreateThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`pthread_create`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create) and the slew of other concurrency functions) opens a different door for design decisions (i.e. "does platform X support thread library Y"); just something to keep in mind as you explore the different API's.

I hope that can help add some clarity.

Comment: A good overview and good effort on the answer. Another key about to note about API and application level multithreading in general, is that each OS (and individual programming threading library) generally implement threads differently (though there are attempts to create portable threading choices). So writing multithreaded code for one OS does not guaranteed it will be portable to another.

Comment: Wow, great reply txtechhelp. That cleared everything up. I didn't know there was such thing as an "OS level thread." Where could I learn more about threading?

Comment: @collinskewl2, I've edited my answer, but the "OS level" is to denote at a higher (logical) level and not the hardware itself (i.e. the CPU). I've also put some links to different thread API's, so you can get a better handle on it, as well, grab your favorite compiler and try it out :)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thanks! I was originally going to leave out the bit about the portability for brevities sake, but after the OP posted asking for a little more (and your comment), I realized I should not have sacrificed said briefness :)

Comment: The second paragraph is misleading, all modern pipelined processors can execute multiple instructions in a single clock cycle for a single CPU core.  E.g. for a high end modern desktop chip for Intel or AMD (Core i7 or Ryzen), it might complete around 10 instructions for each clock cycle.  There are multiple ways that this is achieved, a couple of the main ones are: (i) having multiple arithmetic units, (ii) pipelining: splitting the work for each instruction into smaller chunks so that the small chunks of work for multiple sequential instructions can all be done at the same time.

Comment: @RobWilton I was trying to emphasize the point of '1 at time' without getting too low-level, but totally agree in how that could be misunderstood. I reworded a bit to add that clarity. Thanks for catch!

Answer (score 0):

I actually researched this very topic in my Operating Systems class.

When using threads, a good rule of thumb for increased performance for CPU bound processes is to use an equal number of threads as cores, except in the case of a hyper-threaded system in which case one should use twice as many cores. The other rule of thumb that can be concluded is for I/O bound processes. This rule is to quadruple the number threads per cores, except for the case of a hyper-threaded system than one can quadruple the number of threads per core.

Comment: *This rule is to quadruple the number threads per cores, except for the case of a hyper-threaded system than one can quadruple the number of threads per core.* - both sound similar. Otherwise, a good short answer!

Comment: libx264 (the video encoder) defaults to starting N=1.5x logical CPU count threads.  It has complicated work-dispatching because of dependencies in the computations, so it can use simpler dispatching logic and let the OS take care of running threads that are runnable.  In simpler cases, though, yeah one thread per logical core is sensible for CPU-bound worker threads.